# Why does VSCode's "Go to definition" fail on my project using Webpack alias?

Tags: javascript, webpack, visual-studio-code

This is a followup to [vscode issue #16320](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16320#issuecomment-412954993), to which vscode dev Matt Bierner suggests I ask here.

---

Recent versions of VS Code...

1. ... have a [Go to definition](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition) feature, triggered by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> on a symbol...
2. ... and also support (via `jsconfig.json` configuration) webpack aliases, a webpack feature enabling prefixes for import lines for friendlier imports (see [vscode documentation for Webpack aliases](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases)). For example, aliasing `/src/api` to `*` will let me type `import foo from */users` instead of `import foo from ../../../../src/api/users`.

But in some uses cases, they fail together. I built a [minimal broken test project (zip, 3kB)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/enj8q647rf7kfco/vscode-jsconfig-path-webpack-no-gotodef.zip?dl=1) for my use case. Can anyone give a look at it and see if I'm doing anything wrong or if it looks like a bug?

Extract the zip and see `README.md`: path autocompletion works, but not "peek" or "Go to definition".

- Skim through the js files to check I'm not asking you to run anything nefarious.
- `npm install && npm run build && node dist/index.js`
  → Install & build both succeed, indicating Webpack is happy. Run logs `[1, 2, 3]`.
- Now, run `code /path/to/project` and open `src/index.js`
  On line 5, try to <kbd>F12</kbd> on `getLinks`
  → `No definition found for 'getLinks'`

Am I still doing something wrong in my `jsconfig.json`, or is this a bug? (the multiple levels of exports, maybe?)

Comment: how about trying `"paths": { "api/*": ["./src/api/*"] }` and importing `Links` with `import { Links } from 'api/resources';`

Comment: @jackjop nope, doesn't work for me (updated [jsconfig.json, index.js], restarted vscode). Does this work for you? Does my original config work for you? Thanks for the fast feedback! 

Comment: yep, changing these worked for me. But import might be wrong here. Can you also try changing your index.js to `import * as Links from './links'; ---- export { Links };`

Comment: @jackjop A. rewriting the import/export in `api/index.js` and B. rewriting the prefix as `api/...` as you suggest works (doing A or B doesn't, both have to be done for `Go to Definition` to work). But webpack *is* happy with my original project and does compiles it successfully without warning. Would you say Webpack is excessively tolerant, or vscode isn't enough?

Comment: I would say vscode isn't enough because Webstorm can use webpack aliases perfectly

Comment: @jackjop . I'm marking your answer as accepted, because props for the fast feedback and with that I can come back to the github issue, but passersby: that's a vscode bug, the "real solution" is a fix in vscode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `src/index.js` like below:

```
import { Links } from 'api/resources';
```

Change `jsconfig.json` file paths like below:

```
"paths": { 
    "api/*": ["./src/api/*"] 
}
```

in `src/api/resourcers/index.js` change your import export like below:

```
import * as Links from './links';

export {Links};
```

also install this package and use `--save-dev` option

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

after this add the plugin to `babel plugins` in `package.json` I don't know if you need the root prefix plugin but I removed it.

```
"plugins": [
  "transform-runtime",
  "transform-export-extensions",
  "transform-object-rest-spread",
  [
    "module-resolver", {
    "root": ["./src"],
    "alias": {
      "api": "./src/api"
    }
  }
]
```

you can also change api to resources but in that case you need to import like below:

```
import {Links} from 'resources/index';
```

---

Also please check [this](https://medium.com/@justintulk/solve-module-import-aliasing-for-webpack-jest-and-vscode-74007ce4adc9) and [this.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14907)

Answer (score 8):

Accepted answer is correct, except my solution was simply:

```js
import something from '~/something';
```

`jsconfig.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this one worked straight away, and was very simple